# Check if objectAtIndex is nil without receiving error?

Tags: objective-c, indexing, nsmutablearray, nsarray

How can I check to see if an object in an NSMutableArray is nil or not without getting the error `index .. beyond bounds for empty array`? I receive the error using the following code:

```
if (![self.sortedArray objectAtIndex:[alphabet indexOfObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", (char) [letter characterAtIndex:0]]]]) {
      NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:countryDict];
      [self.sortedArray addObject:arr];
}
else {
      [[self.sortedArray objectAtIndex:[alphabet indexOfObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", (char) [letter characterAtIndex:0]]]] addObject:countryDict];
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply check that the index you are using is lower than `[array count]` ;)